# How does one use loops in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In TSQL, I would like to change the following code from have to use hard coded dhomes to using a loop for optimization. My failed attempt at trying to add a loop is also included.

```
Declare  @dhome Tinyint, @bp smallint, @lr smallint, @q smallint

    // Set @dhome = 1
  While(@dhome <= 3) // My attempt to add a loop

  SELECT @lr = MAX(NQdDate), @q = NQd
  FROM NQdHistory
  WHERE dhomeId = @dhome 
  GROUP BY NQdDate, NQd

  SELECT @bd = COUNT(*)
  FROM bdhome
  WHERE NQdDate= @lr AND dhomeID= @dhome 

  DELETE FROM ND1 WITH(XLOCK)
  WHERE dhomeID= @dhome  AND NQdDate= @lr

  UPDATE NQdHistory
  SET Nbd = @q - @@RowCount - @bp, NBd = @bp
  WHERE NQdDate= @lr AND dhomeID= @dhome 

  Set @dhome = @dhome +1 //My attempt to end a loop
```

Comment: You need a BEGIN and END under your while

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You're missing your begin and end.  Also, be sure to give `@dhome` a value.  It looks like you started to and have it commented out on your third line:

```
Declare  @dhome Tinyint, @bp smallint, @lr smallint, @q smallint

    // Set @dhome = 1
While(@dhome <= 3) // My attempt to add a loop
begin
  SELECT @lr = MAX(NQdDate), @q = NQd
  FROM NQdHistory
  WHERE dhomeId = @dhome 
  GROUP BY NQdDate, NQd

  SELECT @bd = COUNT(*)
  FROM bdhome
  WHERE NQdDate= @lr AND dhomeID= @dhome 

  DELETE FROM ND1 WITH(XLOCK)
  WHERE dhomeID= @dhome  AND NQdDate= @lr

  UPDATE NQdHistory
  SET Nbd = @q - @@RowCount - @bp, NBd = @bp
  WHERE NQdDate= @lr AND dhomeID= @dhome 

  Set @dhome = @dhome +1 //My attempt to end a loop
end
```

If you're familiar with C/C#/C++, think of T-SQL's Begin and End like curly braces `{` and `}`, if you're more familiar with VB `Then` and `End If`.  Or more like pascals `Begin` and `End`.  You get the idea :)

Comment: Would it be the same way if I did a for loop in TSQL?

Comment: There's not really a such thing as a `FOR` loop in T-SQL.  The code in the answer basically simulates the functionality of a `FOR` loop, however.

Answer (score 2):

Missing a begin and end on your while.

[WHILE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1**

```
DECLARE @I INT,@COUNTVAR INT
SET @I = 1
DECLARE @Parent_Child TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),ParentPositionID INT NULL,ChildPositionId Int)

INSERT INTO @Parent_Child(ParentPositionID,ChildPositionId) 
SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_POSITION_ID,CHILD_POSITION_ID from tblPOSITION_HIERARCHY 
--WHERE CHILD_POSITION_ID IN (--YOUR CONDITION IF ANY)
SELECT @COUNTVAR =COUNT(*) FROM @PTS_Parent_Child
DECLARE @int_SUPE_POSITION_ID INT, @int_CHILD_POSITION_ID INT
 --loop through records here 
WHILE @I <= @COUNTVAR
BEGIN
SELECT @int_SUPE_POSITION_ID=ParentPositionID,@int_CHILD_POSITION_ID=ChildPositionId  FROM @Parent_Child WHERE ID=@I   
--Whatever you want to do with records
SET @I=@I+1
END
```

**Example 2**

Just another approach if you are fine using temp tables.I have   personally tested this and it will not cause any exception (even if temp table does not have any data.)

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (
      ROWID int identity(1,1) primary key,
      HIERARCHY_ID_TO_UPDATE int,
    )
    --INSERT DATA INTO TEMP TABLE USING INSERT INTO CLAUSE OR FOR EAXMPLE BELOW
    --INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES(1)
    --INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES(2)
    --INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES(4)
    --INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES(6)
    --INSERT INTO ##TempTable VALUES(8)


    DECLARE @MAXID INT
    SET @COUNTER =1
    SELECT @MAXID=COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable
    --PRINT @MAXID
    WHILE (@MAXID > 0)
    BEGIN
         --DO THE PROCESSING HERE 
         SELECT @HIERARCHY_ID_TO_UPDATE =PT.HIERARCHY_ID_TO_UPDATE FROM      #TempTable  PT WHERE ROWID=@COUNTER
         --PRINT '@MAXID VALUE '
         --PRINT  @MAXID
        SET @MAXID=@MAXID-1
        SET @COUNTER =@COUNTER + 1
    End


    If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempTable
    END
```